# How to change location of search bar in wordpress mobile theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search, mobile

I'm a bit of a newbie with web design. I'm self-hosting a Wordpress site at noisehole.com, and I'm using the MH Magazine template. I've created a child theme and modified it to include a search bar above the header, outside of the standard widget areas.

However, when viewing the site on a mobile device (or just shrinking the horizontal width of the browser window), you can see that the search bar and the Noisehole logo do not cooperate well with each other.

I'd like to set the page up so that with sufficient width, the search bar appears to the right of the Noisehole logo (as it does today), but on a mobile browser (or small-width desktop browser), the search box appears below the Noisehole logo.

I believe I need to do this in the header.php file (with some additional styling rules in styles.css), but I'm just not strong enough with my PHP skills yet to figure out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you able to tell if the theme you are using is considered responsive? The symptoms described sound like a media query in the CSS file is making elements change about a bit, which is messing up how you want to display your search bar.

Comment: Yes, it's considered responsive, though it's a bit ham-fisted. It simply looks at the width of the page and switches to a different CSS layout if it determines the width is "mobile", whether it's actually mobile or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would suggest hiding the search bar when the browser width falls under 768px (with a CSS media query) and making a new search bar appear in the mobile friendly nav bar at the top only when the browser is under 768px (if that makes sense!)

That's with the assumption that you want the search bar on the mobile version.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding something, but CSS alone cannot take an action on an element's property such as width without additional javascript, correct? I'm definitely getting out of my very limited area of expertise if that's the case.

Comment: Yup it can, that's what a CSS media query is, basically a conditional CSS statement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting close here. The only remaining part that's confusing me is that

`@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .search {
  display: none;
 }` 
doesn't hide the search bar, but if I sub in a different CSS element like .header-wrap, it does. .header-wrap hides the logo as well, though.

Comment: @KevinMeyer can't help more right now, but if you're still stuck tomorrow, I will throw something together for you, I'll check back here then!